# Laravel 8 runs with npm run in the development environment and reports an error

Tags: laravel-8, node-modules, npm-install

ERROR in ./resources/assets/js/iview.js 6:0-22
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve './bootstrap' in '/mnt/html/wosi/lfs_laravel81/resources/assets/js'
Did you miss the leading dot in 'resolve.extensions'? Did you mean '[".*",".wasm",".mjs",".js",".jsx",".json"]' instead of '["*",".wasm",".mjs",".js",".jsx",".json"]'?

ERROR in ./node_modules/filemanager/index.js 1:0-39
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve './filemanager' in '/mnt/html/wosi/lfs_laravel81/node_modules/filemanager'
Did you miss the leading dot in 'resolve.extensions'? Did you mean '[".*",".wasm",".mjs",".js",".jsx",".json"]' instead of '["*",".wasm",".mjs",".js",".jsx",".json"]'?

ERROR in ./resources/assets/sass/iview.scss
Module build failed (from ./node_modules/mini-css-extract-plugin/dist/loader.js):
ModuleBuildError: Module build failed (from ./node_modules/sass-loader/dist/cjs.js):
SassError: Can't find stylesheet to import.
╷
6 │ @import "variables";
│         ^^^^^^^^^^^
╵
resources/assets/sass/iview.scss 6:9  root stylesheet
at processResult (/mnt/html/lfs_laravel8/node_modules/webpack/lib/NormalModule.js:764:19)
at /mnt/html/lfs_laravel8/node_modules/webpack/lib/NormalModule.js:866:5
at /mnt/html/lfs_laravel8/node_modules/loader-runner/lib/LoaderRunner.js:400:11
at /mnt/html/lfs_laravel8/node_modules/loader-runner/lib/LoaderRunner.js:252:18
at context.callback (/mnt/html/lfs_laravel8/node_modules/loader-runner/lib/LoaderRunner.js:124:13)
at Object.loader (/mnt/html/wosi/lfs_laravel81/node_modules/sass-loader/dist/index.js:69:5)

ERROR in ./node_modules/vue-json-editor/vue-json-editor.vue 1:0
Module parse failed: Unexpected token (1:0)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type, currently no loaders are configured to process this file. See https://webpack.js.org/concepts#loaders

> 

|   
|

1 ERROR in child compilations (Use 'stats.children: true' resp. '--stats-children' for more details)
webpack compiled with 5 errors
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! @ development: `mix`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the @ development script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /root/.npm/_logs/2023-08-04T02_01_57_963Z-debug.log
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! @ dev: `npm run development`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the @ dev script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /root/.npm/_logs/2023-08-04T02_01_58_061Z-debug.log

/mnt/html/# node -v
v14.21.3
/mnt/html/# npm -v
6.14.18

Please tell me how to solve this problem, I have tried many times！
Please tell me how to solve this problem, I have tried many times！

thank you very much！
thank you very much！